# Receiving multiple IDs from a database to create multiple polylines in Google Maps

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, google-maps

I'm making an Android app that sends GPS coordinates to a web app that displays the location (and movement) of a user and updates every second. I need to allow the map to display and update multiple user's locations at the same time, but I'm unsure of how to do this. When a user presses a button, a random number is generated to identify that person. The coordinates are continually sent to the database, along with the ID. The map program pulls the location every second using AJAX and updates the location on the map. This all works.

What I need to do is allow the program to check for new IDs and if a new one is found, create a new polyline for that user and keep updating the location of all the users in real time. I know that JavaScript does not have classes, but can sort of be created with functions. Below is my code, if someone could point me in a direction, mainly where and how I would make this "class."

```
     function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 6,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    }


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions); 
    var points = [];//new google.maps.LatLng(35, -75)];           
      $(function () {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setInterval(function(){
                $.ajax({                                      
                    url: 'api.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
                    data: "",                        //you can insert url arguments here to pass to api.php for example "id=5&parent=6"
                    dataType: 'json',                //data format      
                    success: function(data){          //on recieve of reply                          
                        lati = data[1];              //get id
                        longi = data[2];           //get name
                        var myLatlngt = new google.maps.LatLng(lati, longi);

                        points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lati, longi));

                        var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                            map: map,
                            path: points,
                            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                            strokeWeight: 2
                            });
                        polyline.setMap(map);

                        //var image = 'icon.png';
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: myLatlngt,
                            title:"Hello World!",
                            //icon: image
                        });
                        marker.setMap(map);

                    } 
                });
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
```

The 'api,php' is the file that pulls the tuples from the database and the `lati = data[1]` is the latitude extracted from the returned array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your example does draw only one polyline each second. you should be able to send all the new polylines for the current map boundries, delete the old ones, and populate the new ones.

to delete the polyline:

```
polyline.setMap(null);
```

to receive the polylines for the current map boundries:

```
var bounds = map.getBounds();
var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
var coord_xpos = northEast.lng();
var coord_xneg = southWest.lng();
var coord_ypos = northEast.lat();
var coord_yneg = southWest.lat();
```

the ajax should send "data" variable like:

```
$.ajax({
data: {coord_xpos: coord_xpos, coord_xneg: coord_xneg, coord_ypos: coord_ypos, coord_yneg: coord_yneg}
```

Comment: Currently, the polyline keeps "growing" it basically tracks and shows the user in real time by fetching coords from the database and adding them to the array (var points) which continues to build the polyline. I need to be able to track multiple users at the same time. It could look for 'user1' in the DB and add to that polyline and also look for 'user2' and build that polyline at the same time. Like if I instantiate a new object for each user.

Comment: then, you need to draw multiple polylines, one for each user.

Comment: Yes, but how do I do this without deleting the other ones?